# Players not spawning in game [Mirror]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I'm following a tutorial on how to **spawn players** into a game on a network and I'm having some problems. The players are **not spawning** in. The issue I think is with these methods:

```
public override void OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection conn)
{
     base.OnClientConnect(conn);
     OnClientConnected?.Invoke();
}

public override void OnClientDisconnect(NetworkConnection conn)
{
    base.OnClientDisconnect(conn);
    OnClientDisconnected?.Invoke();
}
```

I'm getting the following **warnings**:

```
warning CS0672: Member 'NetworkManagerLobby.OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection)' overrides obsolete member 'NetworkManager.OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection)'. Add the Obsolete attribute to 'NetworkManagerLobby.OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection)'.

warning CS0672: Member 'NetworkManagerLobby.OnClientDisconnect(NetworkConnection)' overrides obsolete member 'NetworkManager.OnClientDisconnect(NetworkConnection)'. Add the Obsolete attribute to 'NetworkManagerLobby.OnClientDisconnect(NetworkConnection)'.

warning CS0618: 'NetworkManager.OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection)' is obsolete: 'Remove the NetworkConnection parameter in your override and use NetworkClient.connection instead.'

warning CS0618: 'NetworkManager.OnClientDisconnect(NetworkConnection)' is obsolete: 'Remove the NetworkConnection parameter in your override and use NetworkClient.connection instead.'
```

Unity version 2021.5.3f1

[UPDATED]

I managed to get rid of the warnings by changing the methods like this:

```
    public override void OnClientConnect()
    {
        base.OnClientConnect();
        OnClientConnected?.Invoke();
    }

    public virtual void OnServerDisconnect()
    {
        base.OnClientDisconnect();
        OnClientDisconnected?.Invoke();
    }
```

However, the players are still not spawning. I have a `PlayerSpawnSystem` script that handles spawning the players in but the `SpawnPlayer` method is not getting called.

```
    public override void OnStartServer() => 
    NetworkManagerLobby.OnServerReadied += SpawnPlayer;

    [Server]
    public void SpawnPlayer(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        Transform spawnPoint = 
        spawnPoints.ElementAtOrDefault(nextIndex);

        if(spawnPoint == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Missing spawn point for player {nextIndex}");
            return;
        }

        GameObject playerInstance = Instantiate(playerPrefab, 
        spawnPoints[nextIndex].position, 
        spawnPoints[nextIndex].rotation);
                                 
        NetworkServer.Spawn(playerInstance, conn);
        nextIndex++;
    }
```

This method is in the `NetworkManagerLobby` script. Using Debug.Log I found out that this method is not getting called so I'd say that's why the players are not spawning because the Server hasn't been readied yet:

```
    public virtual void OnSeverReady(NetworkConnectionToClient conn)
    {
        base.OnServerReady(conn);

        OnServerReadied?.Invoke(conn);
    }
```

The tutorial I'm following is about 2 years old so I know things have changed since then but I couldn't find any recent ones. Is there any fix for this problem without changing all my code?

I'd really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Read the console. It says that functions you are using are obsolete.
Google `'NetworkManager.OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection)' is obsolete`

Answer (score 1):

As the warning says: you don't need the NetworkConnection anymore on client network.

Also, in the "NetworkManager" component, there's a player gameobject you can register so it is automatically spawned when connected to a server.

If this doesn't work, you can still use the NetworkServer.Spawn(GameObject) method which spawns a gameobject [doc to game object spawning in mirror](https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/guides/gameobjects/spawning-gameobjects).

Comment: I changed the methods and that got rid of the warnings:                                                                                               public override void OnClientConnect()
public virtual void OnServerDisconnect()`                                                                             , But the players are still not spawning into my game

Comment: Did you try with the automatic player from mirror?

Comment: Hi, no I haven't, I'm not sure what that is as I'm quite new to Mirror and Unity in general

Comment: In the Network Manager you have a field called "Player" and you can automatically spawn an instance of a player when joining a server/starting a server using this. I'm rather new with Mirror too and only worked a little but with it so it might not work (I managed to make it work this way).

So... what you can try to do is in the client gameobject that holds the networkmanager, you give it the player prefab and tick the box 'spawn player'. It may work

Comment: The `NetworkManagerLobby` script inherits from the `NetworkManager` so I'm not using the built in Mirror `NetworkManager` component. Within the `NetworkManagerLobby` I have a reference to a `SpawnPlayer` prefab that has a `PlayerSpawnSystem` script on it that references the Player prefab that I want to use. So it is all set up in the editor. I think something is wrong with the `OnServerReady` method as it's not getting called after the scene changes from the Lobby scene into the game map. Isn't this method supposed to be called automatically after the `OnServerSceneChanged` method?

Comment: Because your `NetworkManagerLobby` script inherits from the `NetworkManager` it also has every parameters from this script, you should see them on the gameobject that holds the script. 

I didn't use scene swaps with mirror so I don't know. You can check if the callback from `OnClientConnect` works so you know if at least this works. Then, you can debug with callbacks up to the `OnServerSceneChanged` which, I think, should be callbacked when the scene change. 

You nothing works, I suggest you to create your own message that is callbacked when you change the scene.

Comment: Using `Debug.Log()` I found out that the following methods are not getting called. In the `NetworkManagerLobby`: `OnServerReady()` and `OnServerDisconnect()`. And in the `PlayerSpawnSystem`: `OnDestory()` and `SpawnPlayer()`. The `OnClientConnect()` is getting called so that's not an issue. At this point I'm really stuck, I don't know how I could manually call the `OnServerReady()` method after the `OnServerSceneChanged()` as it needs the `NetworkConnection` to be passed in to it in order to call it.

Comment: I don't have any idea, but I'd like to have more information about the project in order to reproduce it on my own so I can run some tests. Can you share such informations?

Comment: I'm following Dapper Dino's Mirror Multiplayer tutorials on YouTube so you could have a look at the scripts here on his GitHub: [link](https://github.com/DapperDino/Mirror-Multiplayer-Tutorials/tree/master/Assets/Tutorials/Lobby/Scripts). I'm only using the `JoinLobbyMenu, MainMenu, NetworkRoomPlayerLobby, NetworkGamePlayerLobby, NetworkManagerLobby, PlayerNameInput, PlayerSpawnPoint` and `PlayerSpawnSystem` scripts. So you can take out unnecessary parts like anything to do with the map system he added to it.

Comment: I also had to change some the method headers from `public override void ''(NetworkConnection)` to `public virtual void '' (NetworkConnectionToClient)`. So far I have it where the player enters their username, hosts or joins a lobby. Clicks ready and once two or more players are in the lobby and ready up the host starts the game. That all works fine, it changes into the game scene but the players don't spawn. Let me know if you need any more information. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Okay so lemme sum up :

you have 1 scene that servs has a lobby,1 scene that servs as the game, in the first scene you can either be the client or the host, and when 3+ player are here in total it switches scene and 3 players should spawn

right?

Do you use managers ? or events ?

Comment: Yes so I have it where the max players is 4 and the min is 2. The start game button is only clickable for the host once all players have clicked ready. The only events I have is the `OnClientConnect`, `OnClientDissconnect` and `OnServerReadied` which are in the `NetworkManagerLobby` script

Comment: It's quite complicated to try explain exactly where all the scripts are attached and so on so if you need more detail these are the videos of his I watched that got me as far as I am in order: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fx8efi2MNz0&t=651s), [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMJS7sVp2FQ&t=947s), [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_W4F5NckCA&t=590s), [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2ypWi553nY&t=1s), you could skip through to find any details you need

Comment: I'm working on it, I'll keep you informed if I succeed.

Comment: Thank you, take all the time you need

Comment: I've followed up to the 3rd video, haven't watched the 3rd yet but I don't seem to have the problem you're encountering. [Here](https://github.com/Feynallein/MirrorProject) is the public repo of what I made, feel free to take a look at it but it is mostly the video you sent (I renamed some stuff though). I can add you as a collaborator and we can dig further into the problem. I hope it'll help though, I'll watch vid 4 as well and I want to keep in touch with you because I want your problem to be fully solved.

Comment: Yeah good idea, my GitHub username is LeanneCreedon, thanks again

Comment: I added you as a collaborator

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was that I spelled this method incorrectly. It was easy to overlook as it did not throw errors when I put `virtual` instead of `override`.

```
    public virtual void OnSeverReady(NetworkConnectionToClient conn)
    {
        base.OnServerReady(conn);
        OnServerReadied?.Invoke(conn);
    }

    public override void OnServerReady(NetworkConnectionToClient conn) {
        base.OnServerReady(conn);
        OnServerReadied?.Invoke(conn);
    }
```

Thanks for the help!